# How to determine which app in web connector is calling the web service?

Tags: web, desktop, quickbooks, connector

I have created a webservice by implementing the web connector callback methods and I have 2 apps running in webconnector for 2 usecases: invoices and customers.

I want to determine which app is triggering my web service so that I can decide whether to push customers or invoices to QB. How do I do it? I was hoping to do it through 'AppID' field but its not returned in every SendRequestXML call. In fact, not even in the first SendRequestXML call. Has anyone implemented these scenarious?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two apps in the Web Connector, then each app should be using a different username, and pointing to a different URL.

If they're using the same URL or the same username... then you did something wrong and you should fix your implementation.

With that said... it sounds like you have sort of a wonky implementation anyway. Why do you have two apps for two different use-cases? Why not just send BOTH customers and invoices through the same app...?

Comment: I have only one app to handle the implementation.

Comment: Why not just send BOTH customers and invoices through the same app...? -> Yes, this makes more sense. I have changed my implementation accordingly. The only complexity I see is that I will need to save the message payload to perform various operations because of asynchronous nature of web connector e.g. GetCustomer -> depending on whether it exists, CustomerAdd/CustomerMod -> InvoiceAdd. How do I design this in a robust way? Is there a reference document that could help me design this flow?

Comment: The way I handled this ( https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php ) was to not store whole payloads, but instead store (action, ID) tuples in a priority queue. So for example, in a scenario where you want to add the customer if it doesn't exist, or update if it does, you initially queue up ( CustomerQuery, $your_customer_id ) with a priority of HIGH. Web Connector picks up high things out of the queue. Depending on what you get back, you then shove either a ( CustomerAdd, $your_customer_id ) or a ( CustomerMod, $your_customer_id ) into the queue from there with a LOW(er) priority.